# Constructing lower triangular matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to construct a lower triangular matrix of a particular form, and as of right now, I'm using the following for loop:

```
M = sparse(eye(DIM));
for k = 1 : DIM - 1
    ak = -z*(1-z)^(k-1);
    M = M + sparse(diag(ak * ones(1, DIM - k), -k));
end
```

Basically, each diagonal from the main diagonal down is constant. I didn't include my definitions for DIM and z since they're not relevant to the construction of the matrix.

Does anyone know a faster way to do this? Maybe a vectorized version?

Comment: Looks like a [Toeplitz](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html) matrix, only sparse. Then again if half your matrix is full, I'm not sure it makes sense to keep it sparse.

Comment: Ahhh, Toeplitz matrix! Thank you! That helps. And regarding the sparsity, I see your point. :)

Answer (score 2):

[As Andras mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756478/constructing-lower-triangular-matrix/48756802#comment84514271_48756478), you can use [`toeplitz`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html) to help you generate this without the need for a loop. You can use the two-input form (supplying the first column and row contents) to create a non-symmetric matrix like so:

```
M = toeplitz([1 -z.*(1-z).^(0:DIM-2)], [1 zeros(1, DIM-1)]);
```

This will be a [full](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html) matrix, so you'll have to convert it to [sparse](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) if you need it in that form (although it may not save you anything memory-wise, since your matrix will be half-full).